# Hypercom Optimum T4220 POS Credit Card Terminal Fails ISP Test With Successful DHCP lease from a pfsense Netgate Appliance with static IP DSL WAN

Tags: ssl, ip, dhcp, pfsense

- This has been an ongoing issue for a
  couple of weeks. The credit card
  terminal will lose the ability to
  connect to the processor server over
  SSL.
- The IP config looks correct, the DHCP
  lease looks legit and it appears to
  have connectivity to the Internet,
  but transactions will not complete.
- For a time we suspected a hardware failure, but the new terminal was fine for 3-4 days and then failed yesterday the same as the prior terminal.
- I can netcat right into the processor
  host plugged into the same Cisco 2950 as the card terminal.
- When the transaction is attempted I
  can see:

  *Ethernet Session Error*

  and then:

  *Invalid address*
- In the error log I see that the Debug
  Buffer states

  VfyCertChain: NOT Verified! Reason 2
     (CERT_SIGNATURE_FAILURE)
     VfyCertChain: NOT Verified! Reason 1
     (UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT)
     VerifyDataBundle ERROR 112 Bus App Signer
     VerifyDDLSysSig: ERROR NOT TCMS Bundle
- This was working yesterday, but today
  it does not work. This happened twice
  before in the past two weeks and
  never previously for 2+ years behind
  a lousy consumer router.
- I don't see any blocked traffic in
  the pf logs that matches either the
  processor host IP or the terminal IP.
- So it appears to be an issue with SSL
  Cert issuer verification but if I
  plug into my consumer router at home
  I have no issues completing
  transactions.
- I can easily renew the IP address on
  the terminal and it always reports
  connectivity.
- This particular model includes an IP
  Diagnostics utility which runs four
  tests:

  1. LAN Connection - Tests that Ethernet connection exists.
  2. Gateway Test - Tests that the GW is responsive(?)
  3. ISP Test - If there were a PPP connection directly involved, I might
     know what this tests exactly, as it
     stands no one can tell me what
     exactly is happening under the hood?
  4. Host Test - Tests that the connection to the processor server is
     successful(?)
- I have restored the pfsense config to a previously known-good point but this did not clear the card terminal issue.

So my question is:

**Does anyone have any experience resolving a similar situation?**

Some other thoughts I had were that I was too hasty in configuring a local instance of BIND or that I have misconfigured pfsense (DHCP Server possibly). I am pretty new to pfsense and credit card terminals.

I am about to deploy another nameserver in this workgroup environment of ~16 total clients (mostly XP & Windows 7) in the hopes that I just got something wrong there.

I am pretty desperate for fresh insight into this issue. This should be a non-issue in 7-10 days when we go to a different processing system, but until then the retail area is without a card reader and that makes small business owners very sad.

: (

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start off warning you that I have no experience with these devices at all. They're black boxes to me.

I'd start by sniffing the traffic between the device and the LAN on a "working" setup (the consumer router you talked about) and then again in the non-working setup.

Comparing the traffic logged should provide a lot of insight into what's going on. Presumably that device, being embedded, will act in a very similar manner each time it's powered-on and the differences between the two configurations ought to be at least somewhat apparent.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion led me to what I believe was the ultimate solution. I noticed from the pcap (at home) that it was speaking IPv6 and I had set pfsense to block IPv6 traffic (at client site). I reversed this setting, restarted the terminal and was successful. The device worked for three days out of the box with IPv6 blocked then as it is now, so I suppose the root cause would be faulty firmware in the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar experience with a CC terminal (not the same model) that would not work even tho DHCP seemed to be handing it a valid address. The key to fixing it for me (and maybe for you) was to give it a local static ip. Once I setup the ip manually I never had another problem with it. The next terminal we got had the same problem until I gave it a static ip address so it seemed to be with all of the units and not just with one of them.

For what it's worth I believe they were Verifone Omni terminals and they were connecting to a Juniper Netscreen Router. DHCP & DNS was provided by a windows server 2003 box.

Anyway I'd give a local static ip a shot and see what happens.

Comment: Did you do a static assignment from the DHCP server or a static IP configured from the terminal? I have configured a static assignment but not at the terminal. I might try that also. Thanks.

Comment: Configured IP from terminal. Static DHCP did not seem to help.